# There is a different googletagmanager in the site code

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-pagespeed, jtag, lightspeed

I see a flow identifier (data stream) in the pagespeed report, for example ...1111, but it is not in the code

Unrecognized thread identifier. A completely different identifier works in the code, for example: ...2222

I looked at the GA 4 settings and made sure what data flow there should be, but it’s not on the pages of my site, it’s a different number

Comment: what do you call a thread identifier?